# Laravel redirection logic after user has logged in and authenticated

Tags: php, laravel

In Laravel, when the user has successfully filled out the login form, the `authenticated` method is called in the `LoginController`. My specific application hits this method after the user logs in, but I need to add an additional step to log the user in to an external API call. If that API call fails, I need to redirect the user back to the previous screen and remove their authentication.

```
protected function authenticated(Request $request, User $user)
    {
        Log::info('authenticated');

        //at this point user is authenticated via laravel
        //now I need to login to a third party api
        $call = app('api')->call('user.login', []
        )->content();
        
        //did a successful login token get returned?
        if (isset($call['token']) && isset($call['user'])) {
            session(['token'=>$call['token']]);
        } else {
            //login to third party api failed,
            //so I need to redirect user back
            Log::info('failed login');
            return redirect()->back(); //send user back to login screen
        }
    }
```

It seems the following logic isn't successfully redirecting, and instead goes immediately to the `handle` method in the `RedirectIfAuthenticatedController`. I see the logged "failed login" message, but it never redirects me back or hits the `return redirect()->back()` line.

I feel like setting up a Middleware just for this logic is a bit unnecessary. I'm trying to find helper methods built into Laravel that lets me call after `authenticated` is hit, but I can't figure it out.

The only way I can get this to work is by adding
`Auth::logout();`
inside the `else` statement. Is this a proper way of handling such logic?

Comment: Once you hit the `authenticated` method, the user is already logged in so it is normal that you need to use `Auth::logout` to log the user out. If you want to hook before the user is authenticated, you should try to move your other authentication logic in the `attemptLogin` method instead.

Comment: Are you sure you want to login the user at all, wouldn't it be cleaner to only login the user if your api call is ok? (Therefore check this at an earlier point)

Comment: I would love to only log the user in after login via the API, but I don't know how to refactor the native logic of Laravel to make that happen @Aless55. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: one important question is also, do you already need to be logged in to make your api call?

Comment: Yes I would need to be logged in prior to making the api calls. But it would be interesting to see how you would approach it if the user should make the login api call first, and then login via Laravel.